# attempting to use imagemagick, blank page

Tags: php, imagemagick

So today after snooping around on stackoverflow I found out about `imagemagick` and it looks awesome. Keep in mind I just discovered this today and I've been messing around trying to get it work for me for a couple hours but to no avail, so I could really use some guidance.

I asked my hosting company and I checked the terminal and I do have it.

Through PuTTY I ran:

```
whereis convert
```

Which spit me out:

```
convert: /usr/bin/convert /usr/share/man/man1/convert.1.gz
```

And then to double check:

```
/usr/bin/convert --version
```

Which gave me:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2015-07-29 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: Open MP
```

So in my public_html I created a file called test.php in which I put:

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $cmd = "public_html/account/archives/emails/2015/November-Email.pdf";
        exec("usr/bin/convert $cmd");
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Error when creating a file: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

When I run `test.php` it just shows a blank screen so clearly somethings wrong as not even the Error message is showing.

Comment: `exec()` doesn't throw Exceptions, so the `catch` clause is unreachable.  Further, `exec()` doesn't normally echo output, so a blank screen is not necessarily indicative of any problems.  Does your `convert` command work when you execute it manually from the command line?

Comment: Also, try this modification for debugging:  `$output = array();  exec("usr/bin/convert $cmd", $output); var_dump($output);`

Comment: The `$cmd` doesn't have enough arguments for the `convert` utility to act on. It's probable writing a help message to stdout (not browser).

Comment: @NateB I applied your code and now the page shows: `array(0) {}`

Comment: Fancy seeing you in here, @emcconville!  Small world, eh?  Hope all is well :)

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy Make sure your `convert` command works manually via PuTTY before trying to execute it via PHP.  See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php for additional help.

Comment: @NateB So I moved the pdf into the root folder and in putty I tried `usr/bin/convert public_html/November-2015.pdf output.jpg` and it ran without errors but I don't have any new files.

Comment: Disregard my above comment, I wasn't looking in the correct spot.

Comment: @NateB So now I can see if I run the command from PuTTY it works and creates the file, however the same command in the php file doesn't produce anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have an output file name.
exec() will not display anything but system() will in certain circumstances

exec("/usr/bin/convert -version ) will not display anything
system("/usr/bin/convert -version ) SHOULD display the version

You may be able to just use convert depending on your setup.

The path to your image can be relative.

- in a filename :(

You will probably want to add a density to the command to control the pdf quality.

Give this a try:

```
 <?php 
    $array=array(); 
    echo "<pre>"; 
    $cmd = "public/html/account/archives/emails/2015/November-Email.pdf";
    exec("usr/bin/convert -density 300 $cmd output.jpg 2>&1", $array);  
    echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>";  
    echo "</pre>"; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting

`Array
(
    [0] => sh: usr/bin/convert: No such file or directory
)

1`

Does this mean it doesn't about imagemagick?

Comment: Try something simple - put the file in the same directory as the code.

Comment: So I moved the pdf into the root folder and in putty I tried `usr/bin/convert public_html/November-2015.pdf output.jpg` and it ran without errors but I don't have any new files. If I do it in the script it still returns the above error.

Comment: In the script do you now have public/html or public_html? To humour me put the file in the same folder as the code and change $cmd to $cmd = "November-Email.pdf";

Comment: You can also try running system("/usr/bin/convert -version" )  and see what you get to prove php can access Imagemagick

Comment: Its public_html by bad it was a type in my question. I did run the version I showed the results in the question.
So now I can see if I run the command from PuTTY it works and creates the file, however the same command in the php file doesn't produce anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99854/discussion-between-bonzo-and-mr-smithyyy).